# Object can't find method

Tags: javascript, html, state-machine, easeljs

I'm trying to make a state machine but it's not working out. I've got this code so far:

```
function makeStateMachine() {
    this.stateConstructors = new Object();
    this.currState = {
        update : function(e) {
            // Nothing to do here
        },
        exit : function() {
            // Nothing to declare
        }
    };
    this.nextState = null;

    var that = this;

    this.update = new function(e) {
        that.currState.update(e);

        that.changeState();
    };

    this.setNextState = new function(targetState) {
        that.nextState = targetState;
    };

    this.addState = new function(constructor, stateName) {
        that.stateConstructors[stateName] = constructor;
    };

    this.changeState = new function() {
        if (that.nextState != null) {
            that.currState.exit();
            that.currState = new that.stateConstructors[that.nextState]();

            that.nextState = null;
        }
    };
}
```

When I try to run it firebug displays this error: "TypeError: that.changeState is not a function" at the line in the update function. When I uncomment the changeState() line it starts whining about the EaselJS library being incorrect (which I know is correct, because it works for other projects of mine). Can somebody help me out here? It probably something very simple (just like always) but I just can't spot the error. I can post the rest of the code if you guys like but I don't think it's relevant.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried dropping the `new` keyword from all your function definitions...

Comment: How do you create a new state machine? It should work if you do it like this: `var machine = new makeStateMachine();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be putting those functions in the prototype. You also should not be using `= new function(...`; just use `= function(...`. Finally, you don't need `that`. Try this code:

```
function makeStateMachine() {
    this.stateConstructors = {};
    this.currState = {
        update : function(e) {
            // Nothing to do here
        },
        exit : function() {
            // Nothing to declare
        }
    };
    this.nextState = null;
}

makeStateMachine.prototype.update = function(e) {
    this.currState.update(e);
    this.changeState();
};

makeStateMachine.prototype.setNextState = function(targetState) {
    this.nextState = targetState;
};

makeStateMachine.prototype.addState = function(constructor, stateName) {
    this.stateConstructors[stateName] = constructor;
};

makeStateMachine.prototype.changeState = function() {
    if (this.nextState != null) {
        this.currState.exit();
        this.currState = new this.stateConstructors[this.nextState]();
        this.nextState = null;
    }
};
```

Comment: This did the trick, along with some other modifications to the rest of my script, as it was severely broken in more than one place. Thanks! But, why are you adding the functions to the prototype? Doesn't the object work just as well when you just add them as variables to the object? Is there a motivation for it or is it just a neater coding style?

Comment: @bobismijnnaam - When you add them to the prototype, all instances of the class share the same code. With the way you were doing it, each instance had its own copy of the function--very wasteful. There's a nice article about prototypes [here](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/understanding-javascript-prototypes/).